# $Y=f(x)$,What should we read?

Tags: functions

What should we read if there is written $Y=f(x)$?.

Should we read $Y$ is the output of $f(x)$ or $Y$ is a function of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

You could say that $y$ is a function of $x$, but it is more common to say that $f$ is a function of $x$. $y=f(x)$ is the output given, for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$